# GraphQL-Number of requests in this schema

Tags: graphql

I was reading the documentation of DataLoader (https://github.com/facebook/dataloader), in which the following statement just got me thinking. Consider the following GraphQL schema:

```
{
  me {
    name
    bestFriend {
      name
    }
    friends(first: 5) {
      name
      bestFriend {
        name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For the above schema, as the doc says:

```
Naively, if me, bestFriend and friends each need to request the backend, 
there could be at most 13 database requests!
```

I don't really get the above statement, can anyone help me out to understand how could there be 13 distinct requests in the above schema?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's make a couple of assumptions:

1. A `User` object returned by the database includes a field for the best friend's id (let's call it `bestFriendId`). The IDs of the User's friends are stored in a separate table.
2. Given an array of User IDs, we cannot make a single request to fetch all the relevant users, but must make one request per id (this is unlikely if you're using a database, but a very real possibility if your data source is another API instead of a database).

Your resolvers might look something like this:

```
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    me: (root, args, ctx) => User.getById(ctx.id),
  },
  User: {
    bestFriend: (user) => User.getById(user.bestFriendId),
    friends: (user, args) => Friends.getByUser(user.id, args.limit).map(User.getById)
  }
}
```

Stepping through the resolvers, we'll see 13 calls to our data source:

- **1** time when resolving `me`
- **1** time when resolving `bestFriend` on the User returned by `me`
- **6** times when resolving `friends` on the User returned by `me`
- **5** times when resolving the `bestFriend` field on each of the Users returned by `friends`

Using DataLoader will still result in multiple requests, but will help cut down on duplicate requests for the same resource (for example, when multiple Users have the same User listed as their friend).

Comment: 1 more for `first 5 friends` - rather relation, not collection resolved by `me`